# Error: cannot find module. any suggestions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, module

i am trying to make and use a local module using node js. i have written all code taking help by angela yu's course and it is giving me a cannot find module error. this is code written in my date.js file:

```
console.log(module);

function getDate(){

    let today = new Date();

  let options = {
    weekday : "long",
    day : "numeric", 
    month : "long" 
  }; 

    let day = today.toLocaleDateString("en-US", options);

    return day;
}
```

This is the code written in my app.js file:

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyp = require("body-parser");
const date = require(__dirname + "/date.js");

const app = express();

let items = ["Play basketball", "Perform theatre", "Study web-development"];
let workitems = [];

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(bodyp.urlencoded({extended: true}));

app.use(express.static("public"));








app.get("/", function(req, res){

  res.render('list', {listtitle: day, newitems: items});

});

app.post("/", function(req, res){
  let item = req.body.todo;

  if(req.body.list == "Work"){
    workitems.push(item);
    res.redirect("/work");
  }
  else{
    items.push(item);
    res.redirect("/");
  }

});








app.get("/work", function(req, res){

  res.render('list', {listtitle: "Work List", newitems: workitems})

});

app.get("/about", function(req, res){

  res.render("about");
})












app.listen(3000, function(){

  console.log("Server is running at port 3000.");
});
```

so when i saw this is not working, i googled and from what i understood the solution given was using

module.exports = getDate //in date.js file

and then

const date = require("./date.js") //in app.js file

so i used both these yet there was an error.
it is generated in the app.js file by require(__dirname + "/date.js") and it just continously says : Cannot find module date.js
which means the path to date.js is incorrect. any help?

Comment: What error are you seeing when you use module.exports?

Comment: Where is the error occurring? Is it generated by `require(__dirname + "/date.js"` or  by `console.log(module)` in date.js? If the former,  where in the server directory structure are `app.js` and `date.js` located?

Comment: @Rohan it says continously : Cannot find module './date.js'

Comment: @traktor it is generated in the app.js file by require(__dirname + "/date.js") and it just continously says : Cannot find module date.js

Comment: What happens if you log `__dirname + "/date.js"` to the console, copy the file path from the console and then try to open it in a text editor (by pasting the path into the "Open file" input of the open dialog).

Answer (score 0):

you need to export your module like this in your date.js

```
function getDate() {
  let today = new Date();
  let options = {
    weekday: "long",
    day: "numeric",
    month: "long"
  };
  let day = today.toLocaleDateString("en-US", options);
  return day;
}

module.exports.getDate = getDate;
```

Then you can import it with

```
const date = require("./date.js");
```

usage

```
const day = date.getDate();
```

Comment: i have tried this yet it is saying : Cannot find module './date.js'